# Django REST framework - different views for the same URL depending on HTTP method

Tags: django, api, url, django-rest-framework

(My views are: **ListAPIView, CreateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView, UpdateAPIView, DestroyAPIView**)

I want my URL like this:

bookshop/authors/ - lists all authors, with POST - adds an author

bookshop/authors/<author_id>/ - with GET - gets details for an author, including books

bookshop/authors/<author_id>/ - with POST - creates a posting of a book for the same author.

bookshop/authors/<author_id>/book/ - gets a book, no posting

** **May be its possible with viewsets and generic views like ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyApiView. But I don't need this. I want the following url pattern with my views(above)**

Comment: The key to notice is that you cannot redirect the url to different view based on the request method , because there is no way for doing it . From urls.py you cannot get the request method , you can only get it from the request parameter . Try creating new views only .

Comment: you can make use of the APIView class and override specific methods (i.e. get, post, patch, put, delete) to write your API as per the HTTP method with the same URL. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views

for the last URL (bookshop/authors/<author_id>/book/) i guess you have to write a separate API

Comment: What do you mean you dont "need" a viewset? its literally the solution given to you for this use case, you can control it to only do the urls you want for the GET/POST and add the other two as separate views. else you do one view that inherits List and CreateView and go from there.